# How to open an existing PostgreSQL database on a different computer?

Tags: postgresql

I have installed PostgreSQL 13.1 on two computers, a laptop and desktop.

I created database using a Tablespace on a portable SSD drive under `F:\MyProject\DB\PG_13_202007201\20350`. So I expect all the database files to be in there somewhere.

I want to work on the database on the SSD drive which is fine on the laptop that created the database, but when I go to my desktop I can't figure out how to attach (SQL Server style) the existing database/tablespace and continue working on it.

Is there a way to work like this with Postgresql?

Comment: It would seem [the answer is no](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/151839/can-postgresql-databases-be-attached-detached-on-the-fly), you have to restart the database. But that answer is four years old. Or are you just looking how to attach the existing database at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that.

A tablespace contains just the data files, but essential information is stored in the metadata (the table name, the columns and their data type, constraints, ...) and elsewhere (for example, the commit log determines which table entries you can see and which ones you cannot).

In short, a tablespace is not self-contained, and you cannot use a tablespace from one database cluster with another database cluster.

If you want to move data between databases, use `pg_dump`.

Comment: I have about 4 databases which should reside in different folders. I need DB1 to be in one folder and DB2 in another etc. Is that possible or do I need a new cluster for each database?

Comment: You can use tablespaces in a single cluster for that, but you cannot move these databases between clusters. If you want to move the data, put each database in its own cluster.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and replies. I created my database using the default cluster location... so should I create a new cluster and then backup/restore the database to the new location? Or is there a better way?

Comment: You can simply move a cluster after shutting down PostgreSQL.

Comment: how do you move a cluster?

Comment: Stop PostgreSQL, move the data directory elsewhere, start the server.

Comment: Thank you, managed to do it successfully. I had to start the server and provide the new data dictionary location. So far so good.